# ¿Para que sirve esta línea en el controlador?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

¿Para que sirve esta línea en el controlador ?

```
db.Entry(provincia).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que saber EF(EntityFramework) expone una serie de estados para indicar que acción hacer a nivel de base de datos con las entidades que esta "trackeando" en su contexto.

En tu caso, estas indicando al contexto de EF que marque esta entidad como modificada y por lo tanto, cuando se haga un `db.SaveChanges` se haga el update de toda la entidad. Esto generará la sentencia necesaria para hacer el update en la base de datos de la entidad con todos sus campos que mapean a columnas de la tabla.

[Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state) tienes una explicación más detallada de todos los estados.